# How to remove background of seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, jupyter

imgur: [seaborn lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjRCB.png)

My result is correct, but there is a secondary "reflection" of my lineplot of the my lineplot in the background that is 2-4x the size of the output.

Answer (score 4):

Make confidence interval = None, in sns.lineplot(...)

```
sns.lineplot(..., ci=None)
```

Comment: `ci` is being deprecated in favor of `sns.lineplot(..., errorbar=None)`

Answer (score 1):

here is a line from 'seaborn' documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

> Passing the entire dataset in long-form mode will aggregate over repeated values (each year) to show the mean and 95% confidence interval:

Meaning the shaded part that you see in the plot is the 95% confidence interval for all the values of a given timestamp. you have multiple `payinguser` entries for a given date.

If you do not want to have the shaded part, then try aggregating the data on timestamps to have a single value for each timestamp.

Comment: You could set `sns.lineplot(..., ci=None)` to suppress the confidence interval.